# SQL Server Special Running Total Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, cumulative-sum

I use SQL Server 2014 and want to have running total. I need running total to calc `Quantity`, `UnitPrice` and `Price`.

`UnitPrice` and `Price` related together and related to `Condition` column. I can't have two `SUM Over` that related together.

Following query is my idea about my question - how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT  
    *,
    SUM(InQuantity - r.OutQuantity) OVER (PARTITION BY r.SalesCompanyId 
                                          ORDER BY r.Date) AS RunningTotalQuantity,
    CASE 
       WHEN Condition = 1 
         THEN LAG(RunningUnitPrice) OVER(PARTITION BY r.SalesCompanyId ORDER BY r.Date) 
         ELSE RunningTotalPrice / RunningTotalQuantity 
    END AS RunningUnitPrice,
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN Condition = 1 
             THEN (InQuantity - OutQuantity) * RunningUnitPrice
             ELSE InPrice - r.OutPrice
        END) OVER (PARTITION BY r.SalesCompanyId ORDER BY r.Date) AS RunningTotalPrice,
    SUM(InQuantity - r.OutQuantity) OVER (PARTITION BY r.SalesCompanyId ORDER BY r.Date) AS RunningPrice
FROM 
    Inventory
```

In above query I used `RunningTotalPrice` in order to calculate `RunningUnitPrice` and used `RunningUnitPrice` in order to calculate `RunningTotalPrice`.

Comment: It would help to understand what you need if you provided some sample data and expected result of the query.